# Magento 1.9 CMS block custom field is not saving values

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, cms-block, custom-field

I already checked all similar posts but still don't know why it won't work for me.
Manually added columns into the table **"cms_block"**, also added all **required fields** in to the **form.php** and now in admin everythig seems to be ok except if I change anything (**except original fields** ... those works). 
What I've done: added fields to the **form.php**, created new fields in **cms_block** table.

Comment: Magento 1.9 mate ...

Comment: check my above replay

Comment: I tried it, do not work :(

Comment: Solved mistery, everything works now